# LibGdx recording and playback sound

Tags: android, android-studio, audio, libgdx

I have an application which records for 10 seconds and playback the sound.but for some reason when I run it the application doesn't playback, only record and flip the screen when it hears sound at a certain volume (real phone).
I'm really out of ideas the code seems to be good, help will be appreciated.

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.AudioDevice;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.AudioRecorder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

 public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter{

@Override
public void create () {
    AudioDevice playbackDevice = Gdx.audio.newAudioDevice(44100, true);
    AudioRecorder recordingDevice = Gdx.audio.newAudioRecorder(44100, true);
    short[] samples = new short[44100 * 10]; // 10 seconds mono audio
    recordingDevice.read(samples, 0, samples.length);
    playbackDevice.writeSamples(samples, 0, samples.length);
    recordingDevice.dispose();
    playbackDevice.dispose();

}

@Override
public void render () {

}

@Override
public void dispose () {
}
}
```

It's the only class in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use game thread for recording, create another thread and start recording in that new thread. I've added small example below that working fine in Android.

```
public class RecordingTest extends ApplicationAdapter{

   Stage stage;

   @Override
   public void create() {

      final AudioDevice playbackDevice = Gdx.audio.newAudioDevice(44100, true);
      final AudioRecorder recordingDevice = Gdx.audio.newAudioRecorder(44100, true);

      stage=new Stage();
      final Label labelStatus=new Label("NOTHING",new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.BLUE));

      final short[] samples = new short[44100 * 10]; // 10 seconds mono audio

      new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {

            labelStatus.setText("Recording Started");
            recordingDevice.read(samples, 0, samples.length);
            recordingDevice.dispose();
            labelStatus.setText("Recording Ended");
            labelStatus.setText("Recorded sample start Playing");
            playbackDevice.writeSamples(samples, 0, samples.length);
            labelStatus.setText("Playing Ended");
            playbackDevice.dispose();

        }
    }).start();

    Table table=new Table();
    table.setFillParent(true);
    table.add(labelStatus);
    stage.addActor(table);
  }

  @Override
  public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);

    stage.draw();
    stage.act();
  }

  @Override
  public void dispose() {
      stage.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ty for the quick answer! do you know how can I check the audio when it's recording?

Comment: sorry i didn't get you, what do you mean by check the audio ?

Comment: To get a certain frequency at the time of recording.

Comment: currently in libGDX, you can't get frequency of sound frame however in android it can possible and can be used by interfacing.